# Why same html and css is showing differently?

Tags: html, css

I am learning the web technology. I was trying to build a portfolio site by following a youtube video. The below code are the html and css code of the index page.

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Nilavro Seal - Developer, Programmer, ML Enthasiast</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../Portfolio/style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="sidebar">
            <!-- Nilavro -->
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="../Portfolio/intro.html">My Intro</a></li>
                    <li><a href="../Portfolio/services.html">Services</a></li>
                    <li><a href="../Portfolio/blog.html">Blog</a></li>
                    <li><a href="../Portfolio/contact.html">Contact Me</a></li>

                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>

        <div class="main">
            <div class="infoContainer">
                <div class="devInfo">
                    <div class="hello">Hi I am </div>
                    <div class="name">Nilavro Seal</div>
                    <div class="about">Developer,Programmer, ML Enthasiast</div>
                    <div class="moreabout">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sed esse officiis
                        molestiae ipsa quibusdam vero.</div>
                    <div class="buttons">
                        <button>Download CV</button>
                        <button>Contact Me</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="devPic"><img src="dev.png" alt="Developer"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

and CSS

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Fira+Sans&display=swap');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Permanent+Marker&family=Source+Code+Pro:wght@300&display=swap');

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.sidebar {
    background-color: rgb(197, 197, 197);
    width: 434px;
    font-family: 'Fira Sans', sans-serif;
    height: 100vh;
}

.sidebar nav {
    padding: 45px;
}

.sidebar nav li {
    list-style: none;
    font-size: 30px;
    padding: 33px 0;
}

.sidebar nav li a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
}

.main {
    background-color: yellow;
    width: 90vw;
}

.container {
    display: flex;
}

.infoContainer {
    background-color: orange;
    height: 58vh;
    width: 80vw;
    margin: 150px auto;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
}

.devPic img {
    height: 58vh;
}

.devInfo {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    font-family: 'Source Code Pro', monospace;
}

.hello {
    font-size: 65px;
}

.name {
    font-size: 50px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: 'Fira Sans', sans-serif;
}

.about {
    font-size: 40px;
}


.buttons {
    margin-top: 34px;
}

.buttons button {
    padding: 9px 14px;
    border-radius: 22px;
    color: white;
    background-color: cornflowerblue;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 23px;
    margin: 0 p px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.buttons button:hover{
    color: cornflowerblue;
    background-color: white;
}

.moreabout {
    font-size: 22px;
    font-family: 'Fira Sans', sans-serif;
    margin-top: 23px;
}
```

then I copy that code and make another html page named Contact.html. But that page is showing little different.

I am attaching the differences of these two pages also.
Can anybody tell why this weird thing is happening??

[image: Chrome index page]

[image: Edge index page]

Comment: We need a [mcve] to see the issue firsthand, not just your images

Answer (score -1):

This is an issue you will often encounter as a web developer.

### why does that happen?

Browsers provide a default CSS file. So, for example, if you write an HTML file without importing any CSS and open it in a browser, you will see that your `<h1>` text is bigger than your `<h2>` text. Also, if you open this HTML file in a different browser, you will see the differences in the default CSS file: The font might be different, the size might also be.

### how to fix it?

To make sure your website looks the same on all browsers, you can use CSS normalizer, like this one: https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/ or the ones in this article: https://medium.com/awesome-css/resetting-browsers-default-css-46ef8d71a42d or search for CSS normalizer.